# The "if" statement does not work

Tags: java, string

I have the following Android program code. It does not work even I input "admin", the correct answer. Then I Toast my input which exactly the same as the == "admin". But it still does not work !!! Is there any trick ? Please help !! Many thanks !!

```
EditText etPassword =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
String t_etPassword =etPassword.getText().toString();

// display the t_etPassword for checking since the "if" does not work
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "<<" +t_etPassword +">>", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

if (t_etPassword == "admin") {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ContactListActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
   } else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Un-Authorised Access !!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).sho();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the language you're using.

Comment: is this java?  never do string comparisons with == always use string libs like lowering both strings and using .equals() or .equalsIgnoreCase()

Comment: `==` tests for reference equality. `.equals()` tests for value equality. That`s why use .equals()

Answer (score 3):

Try to use 'equals' instead of '=='.

```
if ("admin".equals(t_etPassword)) {
```

Explanation: [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Edit: Dont move the text to a string variable, it's unnecessary.
Try this:

```
EditText etPassword =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
if ("yourpass".equals(etPassword)) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ContactListActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
   } else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Un-Authorised Access !!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).sho();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: +1 but to avoid possible NPE, you might want to consider using `"admin".equals(t_etPassword)`

Comment: @MadProgrammer corrected, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (t_etPassword == "admin")
```

change above line to

```
if (t_etPassword.equals("admin"))
```

now you will get correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Please change this line:

```
if (t_etPassword == "admin")
```

to

```
if (t_etPassword.equals("admin"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.equals` instead:

```
if(t_etPassword.equals("admin"))
```

`==` is checking for reference equality whereas `.equals` is used to compare values.